unable to map using octomap mapping
When I run my simulation environment in Gazebo with Ardupilot, MAVROS, on ROS-Melodic-ubuntu18.04, and then run:
roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch for octomap. I can not see the map in Rviz. I receive this in the terminal

[ WARN] [1726332221.391445081]: Nothing to publish, octree is empty.

my octomap_mapping.launch is:
<launch>
  <node name="octomap_server" pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node">
    <param name="resolution" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map"/>   

    <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="100.0"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/narrow_stereo/points_filtered2"/>
  </node>

  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link hokuyo_link 100" name="map_nav_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link map 100" name="odom_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 hokuyo_link map 100" name="map_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 hokuyo_link odom 100" name="map_h_o_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link map 100" name="map_n_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link odom 100" name="b_odom_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
  <node args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" name="map_o_broadcaster" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"/>
</launch>


(rosproject) fctphdvam@fctphd/catkin_ws/src$ rostopic echo
/narrow_stereo/points_filtered2 WARNING: no messages received and
simulated time is active. Is /clock being published?

when I do
(rosproject) fctphdvam@fctphd:~/catkin_ws/src$  rosrun tf view_frames, I get .......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/tf/view_frames", line 48, in <module>
    from tf.srv import *
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tf2_ros import TransformException as Exception, ConnectivityException, LookupException, ExtrapolationException
  File "/home/fctphdvam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "/home/fctphdvam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_py/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__tf2)

I can also see:

(rosproject) fctphdvam@fctphd:~/catkin_ws/src$ rostopic echo
/occupied_cells_vis_array WARNING: no messages received and simulated
time is active. Is /clock being published?

Where am I making a mistake?
